# showing a list from the past 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, list, date, filter

I have a list which shows all the orders that have been placed with the company, from the beginning. the php script for this is shown below:

```
<?php
    if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['cID'])) {
      $cID = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_GET_VARS['cID']);
      $orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.customers_id, o.payment_method, o.date_purchased, o.franchise_id, o.last_modified, o.date_allocated, o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.customers_id = '" . (int)$cID . "' and o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by orders_id DESC";
    } elseif (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['status']) && is_numeric($HTTP_GET_VARS['status']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['status'] > 0)) {
      $status = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_GET_VARS['status']);
      $orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.franchise_id,o.date_purchased, o.last_modified, o.currency, o.currency_value, o.date_allocated, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and s.orders_status_id = '" . (int)$status . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by o.orders_id DESC";
    } else {
      $orders_query_raw = "select o.orders_id, o.customers_id, o.customers_name, o.payment_method, o.date_purchased, o.franchise_id, o.last_modified, o.date_allocated, o.currency, o.currency_value, s.orders_status_name, ot.text as order_total from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o left join " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot on (o.orders_id = ot.orders_id), " . TABLE_ORDERS_STATUS . " s where o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id and s.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' and ot.class = 'ot_total' order by o.orders_id DESC";
    }
    $orders_split = new splitPageResults($HTTP_GET_VARS['page'], MAX_DISPLAY_SEARCH_RESULTS, $orders_query_raw, $orders_query_numrows);
    $orders_query = tep_db_query($orders_query_raw);
    while ($orders = tep_db_fetch_array($orders_query)) {
    if ((!isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['oID']) || (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['oID']) && ($HTTP_GET_VARS['oID'] == $orders['orders_id']))) && !isset($oInfo)) {
        $oInfo = new objectInfo($orders);
      }

      if (isset($oInfo) && is_object($oInfo) && ($orders['orders_id'] == $oInfo->orders_id)) {
        echo '              <tr id="defaultSelected" class="dataTableRowSelected" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID', 'action')) . 'oID=' . $oInfo->orders_id . '&action=edit') . '\'">' . "\n";
      } else {
        echo '              <tr class="dataTableRow" onmouseover="rowOverEffect(this)" onmouseout="rowOutEffect(this)" onclick="document.location.href=\'' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID')) . 'oID=' . $orders['orders_id']) . '\'">' . "\n";
      }
?>
                <td class="dataTableContent"><?php echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID', 'action')) . 'oID=' . $orders['orders_id'] . '&action=edit') . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_ICONS . 'preview.gif', ICON_PREVIEW) . '</a>&nbsp;' . $orders['customers_name']; ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><?php echo strip_tags($orders['order_total']); ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="center"><?php echo tep_datetime_short($orders['date_purchased']); ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><?php echo $orders['orders_status_name'].' '.'['.$orders ['franchise_id'].']'; ?></td>
                <td class="dataTableContent" align="right"><?php if (isset($oInfo) && is_object($oInfo) && ($orders['orders_id'] == $oInfo->orders_id)) { echo tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'icon_arrow_right.gif', ''); } else { echo '<a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_ORDERS, tep_get_all_get_params(array('oID')) . 'oID=' . $orders['orders_id']) . '">' . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'icon_info.gif', IMAGE_ICON_INFO) . '</a>'; } ?>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

This shows the results in the `'<td>'` markup. What I want to show is only the orders from 5pm the previous day to 5pm the current day. How would I do it using the database column marked : `date_purchased`? An example of a value from this column is `03/09/2012 16:46:05`

Comment: What format is "date_purchased" in, i.e. can you give us an example of one of the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not even going to go through your mess of code. But here:

```
WHERE date = CONCAT(DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)), " 17:00:00")
```

Comment: That won't work as the question asks for "between 5pm the previous day to 5pm today", your solution is between the current time yesterday and today.

Comment: So glad you commented on my answer and didn't provide one yourself.

Comment: To make it dynamic, try `concat(date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)), " 17:00:00")`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to [@wes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12428270/623041), using MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```sql
WHERE date_purchased BETWEEN ADDTIME(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY, '17:00:00')
                         AND ADDTIME(CURRENT_DATE                 , '17:00:00')
```

Note that:

- this assumes `date_purchased` is a [temporal data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html).  If it is not, you could use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it; and
- `BETWEEN ... AND ...` expects a closed interval (i.e. it is inclusive of both values)—depending on your requirements, you may either want to specify a second later/earlier than 17:00 on the start/end dates or else use explicit comparison operators e.g. `WHERE [start] <= date_purchased AND date_purchased < [end]`.